# Trying to copy a file from one directory to another in MAKE file

Tags: file, makefile, directory, copy

I am trying to copy the contents mcu_01.ldr file to test directory. But keep getting the following error. I am new to make files so any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE_DIR := test
BUILD_DIR := WLAN/drivers/apps/mcu/
COPY_FILES := $(BUILD_DIR)/mcu_01.ldr

all:    $(CREATE_DIR) $(COPY_FILES) $(BUILD_DIR)

$(CREATE_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@


$(BUILD_DIR)/mcu_01.ldr: mcu_01.ldr

$(BUILD_DIR)/%:
    cp $< $(CREATE_DIR) $@


make: *** No rule to make target `mcu_01.ldr', needed by 
`WLAN/drivers/apps/mcu/mcu.01.ldr'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Is `mcu_01.ldr` in your working directory?

Comment: @Beta Yes it is.

Comment: What Beta asked is if, **in the directory from which you invoke make**, there is a file named `mcu_01.ldr`. Are you 100% sure there is such a file? No spaces or other invisible characters in another file name that would make it look like `mcu_01.ldr`? What happens if you type `ls mcu_01.ldr`?

Comment: Your pattern rule has a strange recipe. When expanded for `WLAN/drivers/apps/mcu/mcu_01.ldr` it becomes `cp mcu_01.ldr test WLAN/drivers/apps/mcu/mcu_01.ldr`. Is this really what you want? If `WLAN/drivers/apps/mcu/mcu_01.ldr` is supposed to be a file it will not work.